# Font substitution

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

What happens when you open a .docx document that is written in a font not
available on your computer?

How can you find the name of original font?

I guess writer select automatically an other font. I tried to open a
document written in Japanese. Writer shows the fond Droid Sans, and all
the characters except number and Roman letters appear as squares. After
changing to Droid Sans Japanese a few boxes are still left. I guess I have
to install the original font on my computer, but I do not know the name of
the font.

Comment: You might want to install the [Noto fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts). They will likely provide coverage for the characters for which your existing fonts did not have glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to find the font, one of [these options](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/7-free-tools-to-identify-a-font/) *might* work. However, I've never tried them, and I don't know how they'd work with a non-English font.

**Edit:** Using one of [these](http://www.investintech.com/content/japanesefonts/) Japanese-based word processing programs may work better.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the [TestFonts extension](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/testfonts) useful for this sort of thing. It works fine in LibreOffice.

It can take several minutes to run depending on the document and the computer, but other than that it works very well.